# How to acess and store ImageWMS layers information?

Tags: openlayers

I want to click on the Map and store some information from a set of layers at the click position.

I thought that I could do it with this code:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';

    var viewResolution = view.getResolution(); 

    var url = [];

    for(var i=0; i<layers.length; i++){ 
        (function(i){
            url[i] = layers[i].getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                evt.coordinate, viewResolution, "EPSG:3857",{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}
                ); 
        })(i);
    }

    var v = [];

    for(var j=0; j<url.length;j++){
        (function(){
            var m = j;
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '<iframe id="frame" seamless src="' + url[m] + '"></iframe>';

            document.getElementById('frame').onload = function(){

                v[m] = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('tpl').innerHTML;

                if(m === url.length-1){
                    alert(v);
                }
            };  
        })();
    }

});
```

The output from this function shows that `v` was modified just in the last iteration eg. `v=[,,,,12]`.

It probably has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the `onload`event and I thougth that the looping clousure would deal with that.

I am new to OpenLayers.